# Amazon Pay allow only specific country for shipping

Tags: php, amazon-pay

I'd like to implement amazon pay. The button works fine, but I would like to restric every country EXCEPT e.g. germany

Here is my code snippet. I tried several addressRestriction formats:

```
$client = new Client($amazonPayConfig);
$amazonPayPayload['storeId'] = $amazonPayStoreId;
$amazonPayPayload['webCheckoutDetails']['checkoutReviewReturnUrl'] = $checkoutReviewReturnUrl;
$amazonPayPayload['deliverySpecifications']['addressRestrictions']['type'] = 'Allowed';
$amazonPayPayload['deliverySpecifications']['addressRestrictions']['restrictions'][] = ['DE'];
$amazonPayPayloadJson = json_encode($amazonPayPayload);
$amazonPaySignature = $client->generateButtonSignature($amazonPayPayloadJson);
```

I receive the error `Error Code: InvalidRequestFormat Error Message: Invalid request format, check fields are in correct format.` when clicking on the button. If I remove the lines:

```
$amazonPayPayload['deliverySpecifications']['addressRestrictions']['type'] = 'Allowed';
$amazonPayPayload['deliverySpecifications']['addressRestrictions']['restrictions'][] = ['DE'];
```

It works...

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address restrictions have a format that is a little different from what one would expect. You might want to try this:

```
$amazonPayPayload['deliverySpecifications']['addressRestrictions']['restrictions'] = ['DE'=>new \stdClass()];
```

The country is not the array value but the array key.

Comment: Thats it, thanks a lot! Do you have skype or slack? :)

Comment: Great  - I'm glad, it works for you.
How about starting with good old email - you will find the details here: https://amazon-pay-sw5.onlineshop.consulting/impressum/